# Accessing emitted event's data inside the inline handler in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling, dom-events

I was wondering if it's possible to extract the emitted event's data inside the inline handler in template.

Current approach:

```javascript
template: `
    <div>
        <some-component @select="onSelect"></some-component>
    </div>
`,
data: () => ({
    selected: undefined
}),
methods: {
    onSelect (selectedItem) {
        this.selected = selectedItem; // this is "kind of" unnecessary
    }
}
```

"Nice-to-have" approach:

```javascript
template: `
    <div>
        <some-component @select="selected = $event.data"></some-component>
    </div>
`,
data: () => ({
    selected: undefined
})
```

is this currently possible? Does `$event` wrapper has any `data` property that would enable us to do this?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @RoyJ  Now I see that the `$event` is actually the `data` I'm sending. never thought about console logging that inside the template. Also, i thought it might be some wrapper object of the original event. Guess that one is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$event` isn't actually a wrapper, but the data you're sending over.

So you can handle it as follows:

```js
template: `
    <div>
        <some-component @select="selected = $event"></some-component>
    </div>
`,
data: () => ({
    selected: undefined
})
```